# Find the simplest form of this boolean function $[x+(xy)]·[x + (x'y)]$

Tags: boolean-algebra

$$ [x+(xy)]·[x + (x'y)]$$

My current belief is that it would be $0$ or $1$

but please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Why is that your belief? If you explain that, then more people are likely to help you understand whether you are right or wrong

Comment: Yes, please describe your conclusion/belief.  Note, you seem to believe it is either a tautology, or a contradiction.  Which one?

Comment: Indeed it is, @Parcly.  But answers like "x" in a comment aren't helpful.  Clearly the OP took a guess.  I would have already answered with a derivation, had OP included work and/or reasoning.

Comment: There are only 4 possible sets of values for $x$ and $y$. It is only a few seconds work to figure out what the value is for each of those sets. Stop working on "belief" and see what actually happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### \begin{align}[x + (xy)].[x + (x'y)] &=[x.(1 + y)].[x + y] \\&=[x].[x + y]\\&=x + x.y\\&=x . (1 + y)\\&=x\end{align}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.